# How to make Vim syntax highlight characters exceeding a byte count within a paragraph?

Tags: vim

I would like to develop a syntax highlighter that is able to highlight text which exceeds a certain byte count. I've written a regex that can match the too-long text if it is not hard-wrapped:

```
\(^.*\)\@127<!.\+
```

Note that the behavior of the negative lookbehind assertion (`\@127<!`) is to count *bytes*, which is useful for handling multi-byte characters correctly in contrast to braces (e.g., doing `^.\{127}\zs.\+` instead) which count *characters.*

What I have been looking for is a modification that will work even if the lines are hard-wrapped and delineated by empty lines (i.e., as paragraphs), but that seems beyond the powers of Vim's `syntax match` commands. Are text properties perhaps the right way to go instead? If so, how would you implement this with text properties?

Comment: Can you share an example of text that should be highlighted ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe something similar to this can do the job:

`/\_.\{127}\zs\_.*`